# Where to store CryptographicKey in Universal Windows Project

Tags: c#, security, cryptography, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal

I'm working on a Universal Windows Project in MSVS2015 using c#. The project is targeted towards phone users, with a probability to go to desktop and tablets later.

I need to generate RSA key pair for the user and store that securely on the device. In windows phone 8.0 I have used CspParameters class for this task, but that's not available in windows 10. What is the correct way to store such sensitive data in UWP?

The code I use to generate the key pair is:

```
AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider rsaPkcs1ProviderServer = AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(AsymmetricAlgorithmNames.RsaPkcs1);
_clientKeyPair = rsaPkcs1ProviderServer.CreateKeyPair(RSA_KEY_SIZE);
```

Comment: What about using [Credential locker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/credential-locker)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the  Windows.Security.Cryptography.DataProtection.DataProtectionProvider class to protect the data using the current user/machine credentials. You could then simply save it to a file.

The documentation can be found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241559

Comment: Thanks. It seems ProtectedData is not available, and I should use DataProtectionProvider instead. I'll look into it some more.

Comment: I'll be using DataProtectionProvider, but otherwise I'll proceed as you suggested. If you change your answer to reflect this, I'll mark it as a solution.

Comment: Thank  you. I changed it according to your comment.